# Booking ad campaign: what days will 'ongoing, renewing' ads display?

Tags: support, advertising

I'm new to booking ads on Stack Exchange. I want to book a short-term campaign on Drupal Answers for an event that begins 3 April. When I select dates 3/21 – 3/31, all the placements say 'sold out'. If I select 'Ongoing, renewing every 30 days', they are all available. If I select 'Ongoing, renewing', will my ad get shown at all during the window I need (through 3/31)?

Comment: The 'Ongoing, renewing...' option reflects a delivery method of x number of impressions running over a 30-day period, renewing each 30-day period. When you select specific dates, you are subject to what remains available within the chosen targeting parameters. Given that you're looking for Drupal inventory over the next few days, it may truly be that it's sold out. Extending to the date your event begins gives you *some* inventory, however.

Comment: *cough* shouldn't that comment be an answer?

Comment: I considered it, @JourneymanGeek, but I wanted to see if that truly helped OP out. I'll take your nudge and toss it down there...

Answer (score 2):

The 'Ongoing, renewing...' option reflects a delivery method of x number of impressions running over a 30-day period, renewing each 30-day period. When you select specific dates, you are subject to what remains available within the chosen targeting parameters. Given that you're looking for Drupal inventory over the next few days, it may truly be that it's sold out. Extending to the date your event begins gives you *some* inventory to work with, however.

Comment: This helps, but doesn't exactly answer my specific question: "If I select 'Ongoing, renewing', will my ad get shown at all during the window I need (through 3/31)?" Can I assume that if my desired window says 'sold out' that my ad will get zero impressions during those days?

Comment: Yeah I'd say that the forecast within the given dates is the one that gives you a true idea of what is available. As a result, I think your assumption that the inventory for the dates about which you're inquiring is, in fact, sold out, and you'll receive zero impressions during those days.

Comment: I'd also add that every ad I'm seeing on Drupal Answers currently is for StackOverflow Jobs. Since that's an ad from the site operator, I assumed there were no outside paid ads running right now, and wondered if StackOverflow ads would get bumped in favor of paying ads. But apparently not?